# Why does my application stop when i open a Activity

Tags: android

Why when I open this Activity my application stops but when I remove the `ArrayList` and adpater it works and doesn't stop?

The error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mypos, PID: 14010
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mypos/com.example.mypos.EditPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1536)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mypos.EditPage.onCreate(EditPage.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1536) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14010 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

And the code:

```
     List<String>List = new ArrayList<>();
        List.add("Food");
        List.add("Drink");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, List);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);



 public void AddProduct(){
            btnAddproduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String name = NAME.getText().toString().trim();
                    String price = PRICE.getText().toString().trim();
                    String itemvalue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if (NAME .length() !=0 && PRICE.length() !=0){
                    if (itemvalue == "Food"){
                        boolean AddFoods = FOODsDB.addDataFoods(name,price);
                        if(AddFoods == true){
                            Toast.makeText(EditPage.this, " Food Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else { Toast.makeText(EditPage.this, " Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                    }else{}

                    if (itemvalue == "Drinks"){
                        boolean AddDrinks = FOODsDB.addDataDrinks(name,price);
                        if(AddDrinks == true){
                            Toast.makeText(EditPage.this, " Drinks Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(EditPage.this, " Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
                        } else {
                        Toast.makeText(EditPage.this, " Please Fill up All the text field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    }
                }
            });
            }




 public  void DeleteData(){
            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                int temp = ID.getText().toString().length();
                String itemvalue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (temp > 0)
                    {
                    if(itemvalue == "Food"){
                        Integer deleteFood = FOODsDB.deleteFood(ID.getText().toString());
                        if(deleteFood > 0){
                            Toast.makeText(EditPage.this," Successfully Deleted Food :(",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(EditPage.this," Something Went Wrong :(",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else{}

                        if(itemvalue == "Drinks"){
                            Integer deleteFood = FOODsDB.deleteDrinks(ID.getText().toString());
                            if(deleteFood > 0){
                                Toast.makeText(EditPage.this," Successfully Deleted Drink ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(EditPage.this," Something Went Wrong :(",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } else{}
                    }
                    else{
                    Toast.makeText(EditPage.this," Please Input an ID",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                }
            });
            }




  public void UpdateData(){
                        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                            int temp = ID.getText().toString().length();
                                String itemvalue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                if (temp > 0 ){
                                    if(itemvalue == "Food"){
                                    boolean update = FOODsDB.updateData(ID.getText().toString(), NAME.getText().toString(),PRICE.getText().toString());
                                        if (update == true){
                                            Toast.makeText(EditPage.this," Successfully Updated Food",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }else{
                                            Toast.makeText(EditPage.this," Something Went Wrong :(",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }else{}
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(EditPage.this," Please Input an ID",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        })
            }
```

Comment: Hey @Potpoopow, it's hard to know given the code that you've added there, in particular because it's missing the full content of the `Activity` and the layout files. You'll likely get a more favourable response if you can put together a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As the log said, your `spinner` is null. That mean you didn't init/assign it properly

Answer (score 0):

this error occur when we have not initialize view .initialize spinner before set adapter in it . before use any view we need to initialize view using `findViewById()`

Like this :

```
Spinner spinner;
//add this line in code 
spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner);
List<String>List = new ArrayList<>();
        List.add("Food");
        List.add("Drink");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, List);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```